# I am confused with the output:

Tags: java, string

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            String s=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
 }
```

When I supply this input:

```
rohan
kumar
sharma
```

I want the output to be:

```
rohan
kumar
sharma
rohan
kumar
sharma
```

The actual output I get is:

```
rohan
kumar
rohan
kumar
sharma
```

Note that the last `sharma` in the output does not appear until I press the enter button.

**Question**

How can I alter my code to get the desired output?

Comment: Your title is poor. Please edit it to something that describes the issue.

Comment: When you give the Input as 3 Strings , Output should be of 3 Strings. How did you get 6 Strings in the output?

Comment: which java version you use?

Comment: I copied 
rohan
kumar
sharma 
and pasted it to the terminal

Comment: So the out put should be:
 first three line of input pasted
following three lines should be the exact same input as output

Comment: You have to include a trailing newline to make the scanner process all lines of (whitespace separated tokenized) input. The reason being that scanner doesnt begin to process until you hit return

Comment: Question: how did you hit **enter**?

Comment: "_I want the output to be..._" No. your code does not produce the output you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the scanned strings into a `StringBuilder` and than at last, you can print it as following:

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      String s=sc.next();
      sb.append(s+"\n");
 }
 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Use `sc.next()` if you don't want to press ENTER after every new input.

Now if you copy and paste `Rohan kumar sharma` to terminal, than the o/p will be:

> Rohan kumar sharma
>   Rohan
>   kumar
>   sharma

**EDIT:**

Or you can store the output strings in a single string and at last you can split the string and print the desired output, as following:

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 String str="";
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   String s=sc.next();
   str = str + s;       //append to a string instead of string buffer.
 }
 String a[] = str.split(" ");
 for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
     System.out.println(a[i]);
 }
```

**EDIT:**
If you also don't want to use `str.split()` then append `\n` also. Try following:

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 String str="";
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   String s=sc.next();
   str = str + s+"\n";    //Just string instead of string buffer.
 }
 System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: another means ? I've used only one instance here. @RohanSharma

Comment: Sorry I mean to say, without using StringBuilder how can I get the desired output.

Comment: Than you can scan the input and store it into the String array and print it from the separate loop.

Comment: @RohanSharma you can accept the answer if it is helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here ,sc.nextLine() read a whole line from input .So You can read data from console line by line and can store them in a array and later you can use them .

```
import java.util.*;
public class Condition{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] strings = new String[3];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        String s=sc.nextLine();
       // System.out.println(s);
        strings[i]=s;
    }

    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string);
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append a LF char to the last input line(sharma).

The Scanner.nextLine() return when get a LF char from input, if you miss the last LF char, scanner.nextLine() will hold by waiting for line end, even it already get the whole line's content.

Comment: can you provide some more realistic example?

Comment: Will you please elaborate this with a code. It will be a great help

Comment: I tried by below steps with you code, get the result you want,
1. copy you input into a text editor (sublime),
2. add new line (empty line) in the end of text,
3. run the code
4. copy all the text(4 lines) form the text editor to console

Answer (score -2):

```
package rohan;

import java.util.*;

public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String firstName = sc.nextLine();
        String middleName = sc.nextLine();
        String lastName = sc.nextLine();
        String fullName = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            fullName = firstName + "\n" + middleName + "\n" + lastName;
            System.out.println(fullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but it will print 3 times

Comment: you can change the number of times the for loop runs for e.g .for (int i=0;i<2;i++) it will print name two times

Comment: Code without an explanation doesn't help anyone! Please add an explanation to better the answer